# How can I create a new tag, vsts, for Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: support, tags

How can I create a new tag, "vsts", for Visual Studio Team Services?

Tried to create, but got told "vst" already exists, and ask in Meta ...

*... so here I am ...*

Comment: I think that having a tag called *Visual Studio Team Services* would be the better option to be honest.

Comment: @Burgi Agree, but I tried that and got told it was too long  :-(

Comment: What purpose does this tag serve.  What will be the usage criteria?  Why is a cloud based service going to be a Superuser tag?

Comment: Well there are already tags in this area, e.g. Visual-Studio, Visual-Studio-specific versionsa and VSTS is the cloud version of Team-Foundation-Server. And not trying to be factious, but it's a question for a "super user" about something techie ... isn't this what Superuser is about?

Comment: If it's for the cloud version it would be better here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: The [visual-studio] tag wiki excerpt is mostly info that should go in the wiki rather than usage guidance.  Suggest moving most of that to the wiki, then adding usage guidance that would include directing VSTS questions to WebApps.

Comment: I just went ahead and edited the [visual-studio] tag as described above.

Comment: @SteveC A question about Team Foundation Server is on topic, a question on theTFS cloud service is not.  You should read the help center.  Just because it's techie does not mean it's on topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As people have explained in the comments, that tag might not be appropriate for Super User. If you were going to create it (and I would suggest based on those comments that you don't), you could deal with the length limit by partially abbreviating it, e.g. [vs-team-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vs-team-services). The tag wiki excerpt would then clarify what exactly the tag is about, and people would likely associate Visual Studio with the phrase "team services", whereas I wouldn't immediately have a guess about [vsts](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vsts).

Also, the reason you're receiving that error message is that [tags differing only in hyphenation or capitalization are no longer allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251478/2825369). If I understand correctly, only moderators can create tags that would be blocked by that check (there are legitimate exceptions to the rule, like [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [window](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/window)).